# What are the benefits of PrismaDB's own language? Why not just use Typescript decorators?

Tags: prisma

It seems that in the Node.js ecosystem there's a clear ORM winner these days. I can't help but want to try it out, but the I don't love the idea of introducing a new specific-purpose language into the stack. I like having database and GraphQL definitions in the same place using decorators (Type-GraphQL & TypeORM/MikroORM). With Prisma's specific language, it would require more finagling.

When I look at their language, it really looks derived from Typescript. Models are defined like classes, attributes look like decorators. In fact, I haven't seen any feature in that language that would be impossible or even difficult in plain Typescript.

So my question is, what are the benefits of this specific and opinionated language? Or is the whole thing overhyped?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1805), they want to keep it language-agnostic so that they can have clients for many languages (they already have one in Go). That's a specific benefit, seems more tailored to the developers of the lib, rather than the users...

To be fair, Prisma has many advantages where it comes to type safety. One has to evaluate for themselves whether it's worth it or not. The drawbacks of a separate language for model definition can be outweighed by the capabilities of the client. It most certainly beats TypeORM in many regards anyway.